# I'm a newbie with node. js, I would like to know how I handle a mongoose consultation result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

**I have a Document on mongodb as follows:**

```
Users {
     id: id,
     name: string,
     age: string
}
```

I would like to know how do I get only the age field in the return of my request and not the entire document with all fields.

For example :

```
User.findOne ({name: 'Joe'})
```

This query returns the entire document that has the name Joe. But I want that when I find Joe, only his age returns.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this documentation
[https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

for selecting columns you need to do this:-

```
MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }, 'name friends', function (err, docs) { })
```

Comment: Alternative synax : `MyModel.find({ name: /john/i }).select('name friends').exec((err, docs) => { ...  })`

Comment: I want it to return only the column value that way it returns {age: 22}, I want it to return only 500, which is the value.